# Pass dynamic variable from a logic App to my Power App

Tags: powerapps

I have a logic app/power automate which triggers on an Event Hub message. from EventHub message in PowerAutomate I get an ID. I need this ID to be shown in my PowerApp Screen as in my Power app there is a clickable link which includes this id (https://..../id1) . User are going to navigate to this created link and then fill some value in Power App fields.

Is it possible to dynamically pass ids from my PowerAutomate to PowerApp and set it there and keep updating the ids(my https link in my powerapp) as logic app triggers?

Answer (score 1):

PowerApps needs to know in its session that it should listen to a PowerAutomate(WebHook idea).

Since you started the flow without the PowerApps trigger it won’t be picked up. You can save the dynamic value to a data source, make powerapps check that list and maybe integrate a timer to check the latest value of that list every x seconds or so?